# Capacitor with a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, spring

> The plates of capacitor are attached with non conducting spring of spring constant k. The initial separation between the plates is d and the spring is relaxed initially. Now the charges +Q and -Q is gradually given to the two plates then the capacitance of the capacitor will be ?

**Attempt(my thinking)**: both plates will attract each other so they move x distance towards each other. I am really confused , what should be my approach. I just need a hint or a clue.

Comment: Please note that we do not work out your homework problems for you here. What have you tried so far? What specific physics concepts are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without revealing the details (that's your homework!) you should think about this:

As the spring is being compressed, it is storing energy.

As the plates approach one another, the attractive force between them grows stronger.

Energy is conserved.

Now go to work!

Comment: Got it . ( but that’s not my homework...)

Comment: Oh well...  OK then!